# if $\|f_n\|\leq 1$ then $\|f\|\leq 1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification, normed-spaces

[image]

Is the following enough?

if $f=0$ , then the condition is satisfied. If $f=\lim f_n$ then we have
$$\int_\mathbb{R}fd\lambda= \int_\mathbb{R}\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n d\lambda \leq \liminf_{n\to \infty} \int_\mathbb{R} f_n d\lambda \leq 1$$

Comment: You also need to show $f$ is measurable.

Comment: Is this enough?

$$\lbrace x\in \mathbb{R}:f(x)>\alpha \rbrace = \bigcap_{k\ge 1}\bigcup_{N\ge 1}\bigcap_{n\ge N}\bigg\lbrace x\in \mathbb{R}: f_n(x)\ge \alpha + \frac{1}{k} \bigg\rbrace$$

Comment: The intersection over $k$ should be replaced by a union.

Comment: Also you cannot just distinguish between the cases $f=0$ and $f=\lim f_n$. The limit can exist for some $x$ and not for others.